# How can I automatically adjust the brightness of my screen when switching between dark and light sources?

Tags: windows-10, browser, brightness, accessibility, contrast

Often I will have my brightness set for a dark-mode website, but when I click an outside link I get blinded by the pure white background.  Usually turning down the brightness by a "notch" on my laptop (i.e. `Fn+F11`) is sufficient for my eyes.

For me this is mostly a browser-based issue but a general solution would be fine too.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out adaptive brightness if your laptop supports it. Power management -> Advanced settings.